# Page loader not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, loader

I have a page loader , it will load until my entire page loading complete ,this works fine with chrome but doesnt support in firefox .any other solutions welcome

```
<style>
 #loading {width: 100%;height: 100%;top: 0px;left: 0px;position: fixed;display: block; z-index: 99}

#loading-image {position: absolute;top: 40%;left: 45%;z-index: 100} 
</style>

<body>

 <div id="loading">
<img id="loading-image" src="images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div> 



<script>
  window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none" }   
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a complete ansower for u :)

```
    #loader {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 30;
        margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        display:block;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

that was the style now the body

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: loader works for me . but its not clearing after the page loaded.

Comment: can u please try the one from me, it works so good and I use it in an App in production phase.

Comment: I just tried ur loader with a gif image and it works also so good in Firefox too!
so maybe the problem is somewhere else.
can u tell me if that helped u :)

Comment: when I click on window.onload only that loader works. On Navigation it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi again,
just to be clear, I am '**copy-paste**' your code up here and it works 100%, so the problem is **not** in the code.
what kind of browser are you using, and which version?

Comment: I am also saying I have problem with firefox and its latest version

Comment: Hi again, in this case try to run with other browsers like chrome, and then try to find the problem by debugging the code, or write all of your code in a fidlle so I can debugge it for you :)